# What's the best way to distinguish between multiple routes in Laravel using where constraints?

Tags: laravel, routes

This does not work.  The second route overwrites the first.

```php
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'This is User 1:' . $id;
})->where(['id' => '1']);

Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'This is User 2:' . $id;
})->where(['id' => '2']);
```

I could hardcode the value so 'user/1' works but then there is no $id variable on the request or accessible in the controller.

A more real world example would be

```php
Route::put('purchase/{customerType}/{id}', 'InternalPurchaseController@submit')->where(['customerType' => 'internal']);
Route::put('purchase/{customerType}/{id}', 'ExternalPurchaseController@submit')->where(['customerType' => 'external']);
```

This is a simplified example of my needs, but basically I'd like `$customerType` to be accessible on the Request object.  Currently I'm hardcoding the param in the route and using middleware to extract the values from the url, and manually setting them as params on the Request object. Is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: Why bother with `customerType` as a param at all? Just define the routes as `/internal/{id}` and `/external/{id}`. Since you have a different controller handling them, they should be aware of their own type, like `private $type = "internal";` in `InternalPurchaseController`, and `private $type = "external";` in `ExternalPurchaseController`.

Comment: They share some middleware and form requests that take different actions based that value.

Comment: Hmm I see... When passing these values to the request, is `request` then used in the shared middleware or in the controller? Would it be possible to move that logic to the controllers, or a separate component that each controller access? i.e. `private $externalComponent = new Example($request);`, etc.

Comment: Maybe sending your `$customerType` with the request and deal with it inside your controller? Like: `if($request->customerType == 'internal') {...}else{...}`

Comment: How/why are the routes different? By that I mean how is the logic different in the 
 `InternalController` vs the `ExternalController`?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to call different controller according to route variable try this.

```
Route::put('purchase/{customerType}/{id}', function($customerType, $id){
     if($customerType == internal){
        return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\InternalPurchaseController@submit' . $id);
     }
 }
```

Comment: This might help, but closures don't work with route caching.  Also, my example is pretty simple, in reality I'd need this logic applied to 50+ routes.